# Get list of "new alerts" for azure monitor

Tags: azure, kql, azure-monitoring

I have KQL giving me counts of my alert by severity the only issue is when the user closes them (i.e updates the user response) no column in the alerts table is updated

So here is the azure triggered view
[image]

but the alerts table has nothing [image]

This strikes me as a fairly normal ask

Comment: In a logs based system it is fairly normal to generate an additional log with an updates status rather than update an existing log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making the following assumption that you have a custom KQL query for Azure Resource Graph Explorer to identify Azure Monitor alerts.

Properties, such as alertState and monitorCondition are not standalone columns, but are nested properties within the dynamically typed "properties" column. As this is querying Azure Resource Graph, the records are updated directly, rather than adding a new log (as it would be in log analytics).

Below is a query that extracts the two relevant properties.

```
alertsmanagementresources
| extend alertState = tostring(parse_json(properties.essentials.alertState))
| extend monitorCondition = tostring(parse_json(properties.essentials.monitorCondition))
| project name, alertState, monitorCondition
```

If you need help, please share your query and what information you are looking to query.

Alistair

Comment: Brilliant - I was using the alert table in azure but this is perfect thank you